# Send and recieve data from PHP server in android studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

I've a file in my server which 'echoes' "Hello World!". I want to set text as the return from page to a Textview in android app. Please do not suggest HTTPClient because it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some good clients like [volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/volley/index.html), [robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) or [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), they are very easy to use and provide a great documentation.